# Share list of installed extensions on visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any way or plugin to export the list of installed extensions in visual studio 2010?

I just want export the name of the plugins.

The intention to export the list is to share with other developers.
Sometimes the list is extensive, and take prints is not a very quick way of doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

You can use this Visual Studio 2010 extension, which allows you to synchronize and auto-update Visual Studio extensions between multiple instances.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbaf0ac9-fb7b-4fb3-b34d-ea2269276d3c

Hope this what you've looking for.